# Require(): Failed opening required (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I have created a website using mvc framework, but I cant include php files in files that are from another folder. For example, I have model, view, controller and core folders, if I do the following `require 'Core/User.php'`; in a view file in view folder, then I get the following error:

```
Warning: require(Core/User.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\k2\View\customer-management.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'Core/User.php' 
(include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\k2\View\customer-management.php 
on line 2
```

I've tried using `../Core/User.php`, but the application becomes too messy and i need a cleaner way of doing this, perhaps working with php.ini or .htaccess to allow me to just `include('Core/User.php');` from another folder. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add `C:\xampp\htdocs\k2\` (the folder containing the `Core` files) to your `include_path`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways that I would do this. Both are ways of adding 'C:\xampp\htdocs\k2' to your include path

1. Use `.htaccess`

Add this line to you `.htaccess` file in the web root. You can add other directories as desired

```
php_value include_path '.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\htdocs\k2'
```

Makse sure Apache is configured to allow htacess to work: [Number 4](http://smartwebdeveloper.com/apache/htaccess-problems)

2. If you have some "config" file that is always included, you can add this line to it to set the include path

`set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'C:\xampp\htdocs\k2');`

This makes your code more portable than using relative or absolute path, since there is only one place to make changes when file structures change.

Answer (score 1):

New to PHP, sorry if this is an invalid answer;

The code that produced the error for me :

```
require_once '..app/controllers/' . $this->currentController . '.php';
```

The issue was that I did not have a `/` after the `..`
Correcting to the following code solved the error :

```
require_once '../app/controllers/' . $this->currentController . '.php';
```